# React Formal Typescript With Yup missing properties

Tags: reactjs, typescript

My problem is. Im trying to use react-formal with yup under typescript environment.

I have such very simple code that is giving me error:

```
import React from 'react';
import * as yup from 'yup';
import { ObjectSchema } from 'yup';
import Form from 'react-formal';

interface ITest {
  name: string;
}
const FormalTest: React.FC = () => {
  const schema: ObjectSchema<ITest> = yup.object<ITest>( {
    name: yup.string().required().default( 'default' ),
  } );

  return (
    <div>
      <Form schema={ schema } defaultValue={ schema.default() }>
        <Form.Field name="name" />
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

VS Code is raising error on line with `<Form schema={ schema } defaultValue={ schema.default() }>`

```
Type 'ObjectSchema<ITest>' is missing the following properties from type 'ObjectSchema<object | undefined, object>': unknown, snakeCase, defined, optional, and 2 more.  TS2740
```

I really have no idea what the problem is about.

Do You have some ideas/advices. I can't resign from typescript.

I'm using "react-formal": "2.1.3", "yup": "0.28.3", "react": "16.12.0",

Comment: Which version of `@types/yup` did you install?

Comment: I have 0.26.32 in `./node_modules` but I noticed that in `./node_modules/react-formal/node_modules` I have 0.29.9

Comment: It should match your version of `yup`. Try to install `0.28.3` for `@types/yup` as well.

Comment: Thank You very much for pointing my attention to it. Now everything is working after switching to 0.29.9 version in both places. I wasn't aware that library `react-formal` has its own `node_modules` with different version than my local version.